Unauthorize Google Sign In?
My app automatically signs-in the users if they have previously authorized Google sign in with their account. I am trying to revoke the access now but unable to do so. I followed this: Unauthorize apps from Google and managed to remove my app from the connected apps, basically "revoking" its right from using my Google account as a sign-in method, but even then, automatically sign in is still happening! I have no idea what is going on...
I don't think it's a problem in my Kotlin code, but some weird stuff from Google that still thinks my account is allowed to be used as a login method, even though access has been revoked.
This is how I trigger the automatic login
fun beginOneTapSignIn(activityContext: Context) {
        val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
            .setServerClientId(activityContext.resources.getString(R.string.google_oauth_web_id))
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
            .build()
        sendCredentialRequest(googleIdOption, activityContext, "one_tap", true)
}

